# Office365 can't access the mailbox using C# basic authentication which was working fine before Microsoft disallowed

Tags: c#, .net, office365

I have a piece of code which connects to a mailbox (office 365 mailbox), searches a particular email with subject and then downloads the attachment to be saved onto File system.
It was working fine before but suddenly Microsoft disabled Basic auth access and this code is no more working.

What are my avenues to make it work:

1. Apply Oauth as directed by Microsoft - A bit of hassle and unsure
   exactly how.
2. Create a forwarding rule based on the subject and forward the email
   to other inbox which is not Microsoft and can be accessed through C#
   using basic auth.
3. Any direct script approach in MIcrosoft 365 mailbox when a
   particular email comes, then it must be downloaded to filesystem in
   a folder itself.